# How to use list object in <c:forEach tag?

Tags: jsp-tags

I have two list objects in request. Now I want to use them in jsp page by the following approach:

```
<c:forEach items="${listA}" var="A">
<tr><td>${A.propA}</td><td>${listB[A.index].propB}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Is that possible?
Thanks

I got the correct approach:

```
<c:forEach items="${listA}" var="A" varStatus="status">
<tr><td>${A.propA}</td><td>${listB[status.index].propB}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes try,

```
${requestscope.listA}
```